# Why is my while(matcher.find()) entering an infinite loop? I use it in with Streams

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

What I want: [”Einstein”, “ist”, “kein”, “Stein”] ⇒ {”Einstein”=2, “kein”=1, “Stein”=1}
Using a Stream I want to transform a list of strings to a map finding all the "ei" instances.

My Code is stuck in an infinite loop:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> L5 = List.of("Einstein", "ist", "kein", "Stein");
  Pattern P = Pattern.compile("[Ee]i");
  Map<String, Integer> result = L5.stream().filter(S -> P.matcher(S).find()).collect(
    Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> {
      int count = 0;
      while (P.matcher(i).find()) {
        count++;
      }
      return count;
    })
  );
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

I want to count the instances of "ei" in a map (specifically using streams)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on line `while (P.matcher(i).find())`, each time the while loop checking the condition, [`P.matcher(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) is invoked and a new matcher instance is created to call `find()`, of course it return true every time, hence it becomes infinite loop.

To solve the problem, assign `P.matcher(i)` to a variable first so `find()` is invoked on the same `Matcher` instance.

```java
...
Matcher matcher = P.matcher(i);
while (true) {
    if (!matcher.find()) break;
    count++;
}
return count;
...
```

One improvement is we can make use of [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) to get the count, as below:

```java
Matcher matcher = P.matcher(i);
return (int) matcher.results().count();
```

Comment: Note: It also works like this:
[...]
                            Matcher matcher = P.matcher(i);
                            while (matcher.find()) {
                                count++;
                            }
[...]

Comment: There’s no sense in writing `while (true)`, just to have a conditional `break` right as the first statement inside the loop. That’s exactly what the loop condition is for: `while(matcher.find()) …`. Since the `Matcher` fulfills the role of a loop variable, the most idiomatic form would be `for(Matcher matcher = P.matcher(i); matcher.find(); ) count++;`